# Variables attribute to Excel in R

Tags: r

I am coming from extensive use of Stata and was wondering if I could achieve something similar using R
My goal is to have some sort of data dictionary with different variable attributes (name, data type, indicator for numeric variable and label of the variable)

I use the following Stata codes

```
sysuse auto, clear
describe, replace
browse
```

to have the output below (data dictionary or metadata) that I can export to Excel
[image]

The R code below achieves something similar with several exceptions such as exact data type and variable labels

```
library(haven)
library(explore)

# Load Stata file
df = read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/auto.dta")

dict = df %>% 
          describe()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For those who are not familiar with Stata, what exactly do those commands do?

Comment: There a multiple ways you can access variable data types in R. To get started, look at the output from `str(my_data)`. Various packages provide quick ways to get more detailed summaries, such as `skimr::skim(my_data)`. You'll likely get a better answer if you can edit the question to describe what specific information you are trying to get from your R data object(s).

Comment: StephenOkiya, I don't even know what your question is since I don't know what your STATA code is supposed to be doing. While I can certainly google that code and try to interpret what I find (perhaps not the most robust method since learning a new language can be time-consuming), but I suggest that asking us to do that research for you is not a good basis for a question on StackOverflow. I appreciate the complexity of learning a new language and asking *"how to do in X what I do in Y"*, but I think there needs to be a bit more explanation to get what you need.

Comment: The question is about to be closed (as *"Needs details or clarity"*), so I suggest that editing it sooner may preclude it closing. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for not providing adequate information. I have added more details in the post. Let me know in case it is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the solution to my problem

```
library("dplyr")
library("haven")

# Load Stata file
df = read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/auto.dta")

df2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, sapply(df, attributes))), "name")
```

Thank you!