# Export percent missing, empty, zero, DK/RF in dataset to excel file

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am an extensive Stata user but would like to use R to achieve a similar goal. My desired objective is to have a data frame (that I can export to excel) with summary stats (actually percentage) of missing, empty, zero and special codes(-99, -77 etc). I believe missing and empty should utilize `is.na()` function. The trick is how to iterate numeric and string variables separately since for instance percent zero or special codes are not applicable to string variables

I am using the Stata code below that utilizes for loops

```
* Load dataset
sysuse auto, clear

* Save the total number of observations in a local
count
loc N = `r(N)'


*** Numeric Vars
* Identify numeric variables in the dataset
qui ds, has(type numeric)
qui ds `r(varlist)'
loc numeric_vars "`r(varlist)'"
* Loop through numeric variables calculating the # of missing, empty, DK/RF and zero cases
foreach var in `numeric_vars' {
    qui count if `var' == .
    loc `var'_miss = `r(N)'
    loc `var'_empty = `r(N)' == _N
    qui count if `var' < 0
    loc `var'_dkrf = `r(N)'
    qui count if `var' == 0
    loc `var'_zero = `r(N)'
}

    
*** String Vars
* Identify string variables in the dataset
qui ds, has(type string)
qui ds `r(varlist)'
loc string_vars "`r(varlist)'"
* Loop through numeric variables calculating the # of missing, empty DK/RF cases
foreach var in `string_vars' {
    qui count if `var' == ""
    loc `var'_miss = `r(N)'
    loc `var'_empty = `r(N)' == _N
    loc `var'_dkrf = `r(N)'
}
* Transpose the dataset
xpose, clear var
keep _varname

* Generate place holder variables
gen empty = .
gen missing = .
gen dkrf = .
gen zero = .
    
* Loop through numeric variables counting the number of each cases
foreach var in `numeric_vars' {

        qui replace empty = ``var'_empty' if _varname == "`var'"
        qui replace missing = ``var'_miss' if _varname == "`var'"
        qui replace dkrf = ``var'_dkrf' if _varname == "`var'"
        qui replace zero = ``var'_zero' if _varname == "`var'"

    }
* Loop through string variables counting the number of each cases
foreach var in `string_vars' {

        qui replace empty = ``var'_empty' if _varname == "`var'"
        qui replace missing = ``var'_miss' if _varname == "`var'"
        qui replace dkrf = ``var'_dkrf' if _varname == "`var'"  

    }
foreach var of varlist empty missing dkrf zero {
        replace `var' = round((`var' * 100) / `N', 0.2)
}
```

to have the output below
[image]

where column 1 shows the percentage of empty cases, column 2 percentage of missing cases, column 3 percentage of cases with values -99, -77 (less than zero) and column 4 percentage of cases with value 0.

The code is identifying numeric and string variables separately, count the number of cases based on the various criteria (empty, missing, zero DK/RF) and finally calculating the percentages.

The R code below loads the Stata dta file

```
library(haven)
# Load Stata file
df = read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/auto.dta")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77704650/3358272), Stephen, I think you really need to explain what you are trying to do here. It's certainly okay to have references to STATA code, but unless somebody comes along who already knows both (well), you're unlikely to get much attention here. Good luck!

Comment: In addition, it really helps us to have unambiguous usable sample data. The gold-standard for this is to paste the output from `dput(x)` (or a subset of `x`'s rows/columns, enough to demonstrate the need and be representative of required variability) into a [code block] in your question. Doing so greatly improves the chances of somebody trying to address your needs. In addition -- and this may be handled when you explain the STATA code -- knowing the expected results based on the sample data is always good, too, as this can provide a lot of clarity.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry for lack of clarity. I have tried to improve my post. Let me know in case anything is still unclear

Comment: Okay, we're some progress. While we can infer the expected output from your image, we have no concept of the starting point of your data. As I suggested, please post the output from `dput(df)` (since you use `df <- read_dta(..)`) into a code block in your question; what you paste should start with `structure(` and end with the matching `)`; if it is too big, then _don't edit the `structure(...)` expression_, instead subset the data such as `dput(df[1:5, 1:6])` or similar, then paste _all_ of its `structure(..)`.

Comment: You tagged the [tag:data.table] package, but you are new to R. I'm comfortable in base, dplyr, and data.table semantics, but new users rarely use all three. If you are over-tagging trying to improve visibility, then (1) _plenty_ of people look at the [tag:dplyr] tag, many more I think than [tag:data.table]; and (2) please don't spam tags that aren't truly appropriate. I suggest that if you aren't proficient with `data.table` then you should not be tagging it, as the approaches using it will be contrary to most other "normal R" ways of doing things. Just my opinion.

Comment: @r2evans I've actually just posted a data.table solution without having seen your comment. It's purely because that what I tend to use, and wasn't meant as a riposte!

Comment: @r2evans there's no where I mention I am new to R ;) The fact I am an extensive Stata user doesn't mean I am new to R. FYI, I started working with R back in 2012 but I wouldn't rate my experience as I would Stata. I have used both ```dplyr``` and ```data.table``` libraries hence the reason I have tagged both of them

Comment: @Tobo thanks so much for coming to my aid. I sincerely appreciate.

Comment: My humble apologies! I made an assumption, I'm glad to hear I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly straightforward approach using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# counts of NA/blank, zero, negative
num_zero      <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(v) {sum( v == 0, na.rm = T)}),    .SDcols = is.numeric]
num_neg       <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(v) {sum( v < 0, na.rm = T)}),     .SDcols = is.numeric]
num_na        <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(v) {sum( is.na(v))}),             .SDcols = is.numeric]
chr_na_blank  <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(v) {sum( is.na(v) | v == "" )}),  .SDcols = is.character]

# stack, transpose, name columns
count_col_names <- c("missing", "dkrf", "zero")
ans <-
  rbind(
    cbind(num_na, chr_na_blank),
    num_neg,
    num_zero,
    use.names = T,
    fill = T
  ) |>
  transpose(keep.names = "_varname") |>
  setnames(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), count_col_names)

# add "empty" flag (all missing)
ans[, empty := missing == nrow(df)]
# counts to percentages
ans[, (count_col_names) := lapply(.SD, function(v) { 100 * v / nrow(df) }), .SDcols = count_col_names]
# tweak row and column order
ans[, `_varname` := factor(`_varname`, levels = names(df))]
setorder(ans, `_varname`)
setcolorder(ans, c("_varname", "empty"))
```

Using a slightly richer example than the one you gave:

```
df <- structure(list(num1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, 0, 7), chr1 = c("A", 
"", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), num2 = c(7, 6, 5, 4, -1, 2, 1), 
    chr2 = c("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"), num3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), chr3 = c(NA, "", NA, "", NA, "", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.frame"))

> df
  num1 chr1 num2 chr2 num3 chr3
1    1    A    7    G   NA <NA>
2    2         6    F   NA     
3   NA    C    5    E   NA <NA>
4    4    D    4    D   NA     
5    5    E   -1    C   NA <NA>
6    0    F    2    B   NA     
7    7    G    1    A   NA <NA>
> 
> ans
   _varname  empty   missing     dkrf     zero
     <fctr> <lgcl>     <num>    <num>    <num>
1:     num1  FALSE  14.28571  0.00000 14.28571
2:     chr1  FALSE  14.28571       NA       NA
3:     num2  FALSE   0.00000 14.28571  0.00000
4:     chr2  FALSE   0.00000       NA       NA
5:     num3   TRUE 100.00000  0.00000  0.00000
6:     chr3   TRUE 100.00000       NA       NA
```